# Does awaitTermination in ExecutorService "happens-before" any code executed after it?

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Please, help to understand ExecutorService#awaitTermination(timeout) behaviour.

I'm observing situation when I have in my code:

```
private void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService threadPool){
    threadPool.shutdown(); 
    try {
        if (!threadPool.awaitTermination(threadPoolTimeout, TimeUnit.HOURS)){
            threadPool.shutdownNow(); 
            if (!threadPool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                logger.warn("Pool did not terminate");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ie)     {
        threadPool.shutdownNow();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Does the tasks in pool complete in this case **before** any other calls after shutdownAndAwaitTermination() in same thread ?

Looking into what is happening on production, I believe that the answer is **no**, but I just want to understand how to make sure that any code placed after call to shutdownAndAwaitTermination() will **happen after** last task in pool completes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, tasks could definitely complete after you return from your `shutdownAndAwaitTermination()` method, because you don't actually await termination. If the waiting thread is interrupted, or if it takes too long, you stop waiting, even though tasks may still be running.

Even if you call `shutdownNow()`, your tasks may not respond to interruption (and in general, `ExecutorService` isn't guaranteed to use interruption). So tasks may still be running.

If you want to ensure task completion *happens-before* returning from this method, you have to keep trying until `awaitTermination()` returns `true`, in spite of interrupts, etc. That would be a bad design, so it would be better if your tasks returned their results via a `Future` instead of producing side-effects non-atomically. That way, tasks that complete successfully can be acted upon, while tasks that do not complete can be ignored.

Comment: I believe I need to use threadPool.invokeAll(...) to ensure all tasks are completed. Does invokeAll() creates happen-before?

Comment: @MaximGalushka Yes, if `invokeAll()` returns without exception, all task completion `happens-before` it returns.

Comment: Thanks @erickson I will do this.

Answer (score 0):

from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html:

```
List<Runnable> shutdownNow
Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks,
and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.   
This method does not wait for actively executing tasks to terminate.
Use awaitTermination to do that.
```

There is no way to accurately stop running thread, so you have to wait for already running tasks to finish.